# Playing music in Powershell stops when assigned to button

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-interface, playback, powershell-5.0

I'm facing a problem that I cannot get solved or understand with playing music from Powershell, I made a WPF GUI on top of my Powershell script.
It all works perfect except that when I press the play music button I made the music starts but after a few seconds stops.

Or when moving the mouse over the WPF GUI the music stops and I cannot get it solved. When I throw the code for playing the music in the project it works flawless, only when I assign a button to it the problems start.

So I made a stripped down version with a simple old form and a button nothing more, made an add_Click event to connect the button the code and tested again. Same problem again music stops playing either after a few seconds or when you move your mouse over the form.

Now I still had an old Windows 7 machine hanging around with Powershell V2 still on it, and guess what it worked flawlessly! Then I upgraded Powershell v2 to V5 on that machine and I had the same problem as on Win 10 (1909 with PS 5.1) laptop, so something changed with Powershell between V2 and V2 that causes this behavior, but I cannot find what.

Some examples, when I throw these lines of code in the project it works:

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationcore
    $location = (C:\users\myuserid\test.mp3)
    $PlaySound = New-Object System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer
    $PlaySound.open($location)
    $PlaySound.Play()
```

But as soon as I assign a button to it the problem as described above appears

So stripped all down to bare bones to rule out as much as I can:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationcore

    # Build Form
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.Text = "My Form"
    $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200)
    $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $Form.Topmost = $True

    # Add Button
    $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,35)
    $Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
    $Button.Text = "Play music"

    $Form.Controls.Add($Button)

    #Add Button event 
    $Button.Add_Click({
          
        
        $location = 'D:\test\test.mp3'
        $PlaySound = New-Object System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer
        $PlaySound.open($location)
        $PlaySound.Play()
        
    })
     
    #Show the Form 
    $form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
```

So when resizing the form when the music plays will cause it to stop 95% of the time. But when I throw the code in for playing the music without the button like this it never breaks.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationcore

    # Build Form
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.Text = "My Form"
    $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200)
    $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $Form.Topmost = $True

    # Add Button
    $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,35)
    $Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
    $Button.Text = "Play music"

    $Form.Controls.Add($Button)

    #Add Button event 
    $Button.Add_Click({
          
        
        #Button now does nothing.. and music plays without breaking...ever
        
    })
        
        #Now it will always play to the end no matter what :-S
        $location = 'D:\test\test.mp3'
        $PlaySound = New-Object System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer
        $PlaySound.open($location)
        $PlaySound.Play()

     
    #Show the Form 
    $form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space)*.

I fixed the problem myself, the trick is to load the player at the beginning of your script like this:

```
#Clear the Console
CLS

#Determine Script location
$SCRIPT_PARENT = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

#Add in the presentation core
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework, presentationcore

#Load music player and set location here!
$location = ($SCRIPT_PARENT + "\Music.mp3")
$PlaySound = New-Object System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer

###############################################################
#  here comes a whole lot of code (XAML for WPF GUI etc etc)  #
###############################################################

# Then in your event system only put:

#Play button action 
$MainGUI.Playmusic.add_Click({
     
     #Open file and play music
     $PlaySound.open($location)
     $PlaySound.Play()

})
```

This solved the playing problem 100%.